# Python data frame formatting string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

I've been working on filtering dataframe project. I have a table on Excel, and I converted it to UTF-8 CSV file. I made all my columns on Excel **as number with after comma-2 digit**.

However as you can see in figure some my columns are different. Default should be xx.xx but some columns seen as xx.xxxxx on dataframe. In xx.xx columns I can filter properly, but the other columns are making problems. I tried to filter it like xx.xxxxx but it didn't work again. How can I get rid of this problem?

In wiew data frame tool of pycharm I can format it but this works for only viewing. What should I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [round](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) to choose the given number of digits you want to keep. This way, you can have an equal number of decimals in all columns.